# Function for matrix inversion in VBA

Tags: vba, matrix

trying to have a function return the inverse of a matrix.

I can not for the life of me figure out what is wrong with this, I know it is a simple mistake.

When I try to execute this function within the worksheet, it is giving me #VALUE! in the cells.

```
Function getInverse(mat)

   Dim matrixA As Variant, inverse As Variant

   matrixA = mat
   inverse = Worksheet.Function.MInverse(mat)

getInverse = inverse
```

Comment: If you really need a pointless wrapper around the `MINVERSE` function which you can already use on the worksheet, then try to call your function manually from code, and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: @GSerg, I have tried using minverse directly from the sub that calls it, but get a compile error with "can't assign to array"

Answer (score 0):

Is your array square? MINVERSE only works for [square arrays](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/minverse.php), see the picture below:

[image]

Here you can see what error values the function returns:
http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Minverse-Function.html

> ## VALUE!   -    Occurs if either:
>
> ```
>  -   the supplied array contains a blank or a non-numeric value or
>  -   the supplied array does not have equal numbers of rows and columns
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, it is a 1x1 array

Comment: If it is always 1 by 1 array just use 1 / value. The only reason to get a #value! error with a 1 by 1 array is that the value is blank or non-numeric as I posted above.